# VBA IE Control Radio button that does not have a name or ID tag in IE

Tags: vba, internet-explorer, excel, radio-button

I am trying to get some code of mine to change the radio button on an internal webpage however, the way the page was written the element I want does not have a specific ID. Here is a sample of the code:

```
<div align="center" id="divControls">
    <form id="frmSearch" name="frmSearch" method="POST">
      <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="exec_tbl align_vc">
        <tr>
          <td class="exec_ltxt"><input type="radio" name="search" value=1 checked=checked onclick="collapse('submit');searchOptions();" /> Agent Search</td>
          <td class="exec_ltxt"><input type="radio" name="search" value=2 onclick="expand('submit');searchOptions();" /> Team Search</td>
          <td class="exec_ltxt"><input type="radio" name="search" value=3 onclick="expand('submit');searchOptions();" /> Manager Search</td>
          <td class="exec_ltxt"><input type="radio" name="search" id='searchlob' value=4 onclick="expand('submit');searchOptions();" /> LoB Search</td>
        </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
  </div>
```

I am just needing to have the radio button click value=2 (Team Search).

The VBA I was trying to use is:

```
Sub Attendance_RoundedRectangle2_Click()
  sCSVLink = "webpage"
  sfile = "csvexport.php"
  ssheet = "Sheet10"

  Dim appIE As InternetExplorerMedium
  Dim Obj As Object

On Error Resume Next

  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Set appIE = New InternetExplorerMedium
  Set ieRadio = IE.document.all

  sURL = "webpage"

  ' Instructes the macro to open IE and navigate to sURL.
  With appIE
      .Navigate sURL
      .Visible = True

      Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:02")
      Set HTMLDOC = .document
  End With

  Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:02")
  appIE.document.all.Item("divControls")(3).Checked = True
  appIE.document.getElementByid("divControls").Value = "2"

End Sub
```

By no means am I pro, I am trying to piece it all together and really appreciate any help I can get!

**Updated HTML**

```
<div align="right"><a href="index.php?logout=1">logout</a></div><h1 class="font_2 & uline & center" style="color:#909090;">Reporting</h1>
  <div align="center" id="divControls">
    <form id="frmSearch" name="frmSearch" method="POST">
      <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="exec_tbl align_vc">
        <tr>
          <td class="exec_ltxt"><input type="radio" name="search" value=1 checked=checked onclick="collapse('submit');searchOptions();" /> Agent Search</td>
          <td class="exec_ltxt"><input type="radio" name="search" value=2 onclick="expand('submit');searchOptions();" /> Team Search</td>
          <td class="exec_ltxt"><input type="radio" name="search" value=3 onclick="expand('submit');searchOptions();" /> Manager Search</td>
          <td class="exec_ltxt"><input type="radio" name="search" id='searchlob' value=4 onclick="expand('submit');searchOptions();" /> LoB Search</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="exec_ltxt" colspan="3"><div id="divSearchOption" align="center" style="display:inline;width:100%;"></div></td>
          <td class="exec_ctxt"><input id="submit" type="button" value="Submit" style="display:none;" onclick="submitButton();"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
<td class="exec_rtxt">Start Date:</td>
<td class="exec_ltxt">
<input id="sDate" name="sDate" type="text" size="9" value="2014-01-08" onchange="if (document.getElementById('searchlob').checked != true) { searchOptions(); }" onblur="if (document.getElementById('searchlob').checked != true) { searchOptions(); }" />
<img src="icon_pickdate.gif" id="start_date_button" alt="date picker" />
</td>
 <td class="exec_rtxt">End Date:</td>
<td class="exec_ltxt">
<input id="eDate" name="eDate" type="text" size="9" value="2015-01-08" onchange="if (document.getElementById('searchlob').checked != true) { searchOptions(); }" onblur="if (document.getElementById('searchlob').checked != true) { searchOptions(); }" />
<img src="icon_pickdate.gif" id="end_date_button" alt="date picker" />
</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <input id="uid" name="uid" type="hidden" value="agent" />
    </form>
  </div>
  <div id="divTeamTable" align="center"></div>
  <br/>
  <div align="center" id="divAgentData"></div>
```

The only information I left out was the header which included several javascript links that shouldn't impact the VBA.

Comment: You could use `getElementsbyTagName("input")` and then loop through until you find one with innerText="Team search"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to pause the running macro with Application.Wait, you let the events happen first while the macro is navigating to the URL and before you try to work thru the DOM

Within your With...End With block, add this before the .Visible = True line:

```
    Do
      DoEvents
    Loop Until .ReadyState = 4

    .Document.getElementsByTagName("input")(1).Checked = True
```

Remove these lines of code as they no longer serve any purpose:

```
Set ieRadio = IE.document.all
Set HTMLDOC = .document
Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:02")
appIE.document.all.Item("divControls")(3).Checked = True
appIE.document.getElementByid("divControls").Value = "2"
```

Comment: I updated my code using the new line and removed the un-necessary code but it does not update still. I probably didnt include a key html element in the original post. I am updating the original html to include what I believe was missing.

Comment: I modified the code, please try. This code is based on the assumption that the markup will not change in the future

Answer (score 0):

I think this may help, not very efficient, but works.

```
set inputObjs=appIE.document.getElementByTag("input")   
for each obj in  inputObjs
  if(obj.value=2 ) then obj.click
next
```